# How do I center three images on the same line below the header text with html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center three images below the h1 text but cant figure it out. I have used div to key all the elements and move it with test-align, i have given each one there own id and tryed to move them with pxs but no luck

Comment: Hello, thanks for asking your first question here! Our help will be more effective if you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your HTML. In your case, that should be whatever section of your HTML includes your h1 and all three images.

Comment: you can use display flex to center images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use flex

```css
div{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
}
h1{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<h1>some caption</h1>
<div>
  <img src="http://placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="http://placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="http://placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```